# What underlining structure does a Map in Java use?

Tags: java, dictionary

How is the Map data structure in Java created? Do you use Arrays to create a Map or what other structure is used? 
Thanks!

Comment: Source code is the best answer.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't find the other thread before.

Comment: This question is actually too broad. Thought of linking it to a dup so that you can have a look at the linked questions

Comment: Note that `Map` is an interface and has several different implementations unsing different underlying datastructures.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!